# Positioning three divs within one column with different positions(top and bottom) without overlaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem with positioning the Content of a table Column. At the moment there are three Contents: 2 large ones and one small one. The small one should always be at the bottom of the column and the others at the top. There could be a large gap between the large content and the small content because its also influenced by the other columns which also have a large content.

So, at the moment it looks kind of like this : https://jsfiddle.net/LLx716d4/

Updated (seeable that small content isnt at the bottom of the column): https://jsfiddle.net/oe34tLbd/8/

Errors:

1. But the small content which is at the momnent at the top should be under the others. How can i achieve this?
2. The second column is overlayed by the first one. What can i do that this doesnt happen?
3. There is also a javascript, that expand a field above of the table. In some contellations this movement also moves the absolute positioned contents...

I would be grateful for your help.

**.cshtml**

```
 //Part that is changed by javascript
    <h3 class="info">Information</h3>
            <div class="hide">
              large Content
            </div> 

 //Part that should stay the same no matter, if the Informations are expanded or not
 <table>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 {

  <tr class="Content_table">
   <td class="Content_Column">
       <div class="Content_all">
       <div class="History">large Content 1</div>             
       <div class="updated">large Content 2</div>
       </div>
       <div class="Updater"> small Content 1</div>
   </td>

   <td>
        other columns with also large Content
   </td>
  <tr>
}
</table>
```

**.css**

```
/*table design
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.Content_table {
    background-color:white;
    border-bottom:solid thin #808080;
    padding-bottom:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
}

.Content_Column {
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

 .Content_all {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display: inline-block;
}

 .History {
     background-color:#d0d0d0; 
     padding:5px; 
     white-space: pre-wrap;    
     word-break: normal; 
     position:relative;
 }

 .updated {
     padding:5px; 
     white-space: pre-wrap; 
     word-break: normal; 
     background-color: white;
     position:relative;
 }

 .Updater {
     font-size:xx-small;
     float:left;
     padding:5px 0 0 5px; 
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
  }
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hide').hide();
            $('.info').show();

            $('.info').hover(function () {
                $('.hide').show("blind");
                //$('#Button1').hide();
            });

            $('.hide').mouseleave(function () {
                $('.hide').hide("blind");
                //$('#Button1').show();
            });

        });
```

Comment: you can remove `position: absolute` from `.Content_all`. So it will not overlap each other and also small content will remain at the bottom. Also you can remove `float: left` from `.Updater` class and use `text-align: left`

Comment: Ah, thanks, now there is just a overlapping of the small content and the large content 2. And the small content isnt positioned at the bottom of the column...

Comment: `position: absolute` always needs height, you need to provide height to your `Content_Column`, so small content should know this is the bottom where I have to sit.

Comment: But if I dont know how large the Content is? Is there a possibility to make it more variable? For a short time solution i think i implement a scroll bar to large Content 1&2 and set the hight fixed. But i think that isnt a good solution because the user cant see all details right away and that is necessary here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For this, you can provide `min-height`, may be `200px` or `150px` and if the content is larger than provided `min-height`, it will increase accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Would never thought of that.